# How do I order an R data frame based on request id and previous request id?

Tags: r

I have an R data frame which looks like:

```
User |request_id |previous_request_id
-------------------------------------
A    |9          |5
A    |3          |1
A    |5          |NA
A    |1          |9
B    |2          |8
B    |8          |7
B    |7          |NA
B    |4          |2
```

Each row corresponds to a request a particular user made. Each row has a user ID, a request ID and the ID of their previous request. Where there is no previous request the previous_request_id field is NA.

For each user I want to order each request by using the previous request id, with:

- The order being 1 if the previous_request_id is NA
- The order being 2 if the previous_request_id is equal to a request_id with an order of 1
- The order being 3 if the previous_request_id is equal to a request_id with an order of 2
- etc.

The result of the above rules applied to the first table should look like:

```
User |request_id |previous_request_id |Order
---------------------------------------------
A    |9          |5                   |2
A    |3          |1                   |4
A    |5          |NA                  |1
A    |1          |9                   |3
B    |2          |8                   |3
B    |8          |7                   |2
B    |7          |NA                  |1
B    |4          |2                   |4
```

Is there a way to do this within R? I believe a graphical database package may be the way to do this but so far I haven't been able to find anything in my research (centred on the Cypher language of Neo4j).

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your data in Neo4j?

Comment: It isn't - it's in data frame format.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, but here's what I came up with...

```
df <- read.delim(text="User|request_id|previous_request_id
A|9|5
A|3|1
A|5|NA
A|1|9
B|2|8
B|8|7
B|7|NA
B|4|2", sep="|")

df$order <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
df$order[is.na(df$previous_request_id)] <- 1
df$order[df$order[match(df$previous_request_id, df$request_id)] == 1] <- 2
df$order[df$order[match(df$previous_request_id, df$request_id)] == 2] <- 3
df$order[df$order[match(df$previous_request_id, df$request_id)] == 3] <- 4
```

But notice that we are repeating the same code (almost) over and over. We can create a loop to shorten the code up a bit...

```
max_user_len <- max(table(df$User))
df$order <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
df$order[is.na(df$previous_request_id)] <- 1
sapply(1:max_user_len, function(x)df$order[df$order[match(df$previous_request_id, df$request_id)] == x] <<- x+1)
> df$order
[1] 2 4 1 3 3 2 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a lot more efficient ways to do this but here's how I'd do it using only loops and recursion.

```
str <- "User |request_id |previous_request_id
A    |9          |5
A    |3          |1
A    |5          |NA
A    |1          |9
B    |2          |8
B    |8          |7
B    |7          |NA
B    |4          |2"

tab <- read.table(textConnection(str), sep="|", header=TRUE)
tab$order <- NA

getOrder <- function(id){
    i <- which(tab$request_id == id)
    if(is.na(tab$previous_request_id[i])){
        tab$order[i] <<- 1
    } else {
        tab$order[i] <<- getOrder(tab$previous_request_id[i]) + 1
    }
}

for(i in 1:nrow(tab)){
    if(is.na(tab$order[i])){
        if(is.na(tab$previous_request_id[i])){
            tab$order[i] <- 1
        } else {
            tab$order[i] <- getOrder(tab$previous_request_id[i]) + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
   User request_id previous_request_id order
1 A              9                   5     2
2 A              3                   1     4
3 A              5                  NA     1
4 A              1                   9     3
5 B              2                   8     3
6 B              8                   7     2
7 B              7                  NA     1
8 B              4                   2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

With `igraph` this could be done calculating the shortest path from the first request. This could work:

```
 require(igraph)
 df[]<-lapply(df,as.character)
 unlist(
     lapply(split(df,df$User),
       function(x) {
         graphtmp<-graph.edgelist(na.omit(as.matrix(x[,3:2])))
         path<-as.vector(shortest.paths(graphtmp,x$request_id[is.na(x$previous_request_id)],x$request_id))
         path+1
       }),use.names=F)
 #[1] 2 4 1 3 3 2 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this compares to other solutions as it utilises a for loop, but datatable and plyr operations should help speed up some recursive components:

```
## DATA UPLOAD

df <- read.delim(text="User|request_id|previous_request_id
A|9|5
A|3|1
A|5|NA
A|1|9
B|2|8
B|8|7
B|7|NA
B|4|2", sep="|")

## PACKAGE LOAD

require(data.table)
require(plyr)

## GET DATA INTO RIGHT FORMAT

df <- data.table(df)
df[, User := as.character(User)]
df[, request_id := as.character(request_id)]
df[, previous_request_id := as.character(previous_request_id)]

## THE ACTUAL PROCESS

# Create vector of user ids

user.list <- unique(df$User)

# Setkey to speed up filtering

setkey(df,User)

get_order <- function(user,df) {

  # Consider only one user at a time

  s.df <- df[user]

  # Create an empty ordering column

  s.df$ord <- as.numeric(NA)

  # Redefine NA as 0

  s.df[is.na(previous_request_id) == TRUE,]$previous_request_id <- "0"

  # Set seed to 0

  seed <- "0"

  # Setkey to speed up filtering

  setkey(s.df,previous_request_id)

  for (i in 1:NROW(s.df)) {

    # Filter by seed and define ord as i

    s.df[seed]$ord <- i  

    # Define new seed based on filtered request_id

    seed <- s.df[seed]$request_id}

  return(s.df)}

# Loop through user vector and rbindlist to rebind the output

rebuilt <- rbindlist(llply(.data = user.list, .fun = function(x) {get_order(x,df)}))
```